# How to get a number that has "/" in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a sql query to extract a value from a column term which is in table alpha that have a "/" in it. I have values like:

```
300/500/100
25/50/15
300/500
100/300
25/50/15
100/300
25000/50000
100/300
100/300
25/50/15
100/300/100
300/500/100
300/500/300
25/50/15
25000/50000
100/300
```

Output should be

```
300/500
100/300
100/300
100/300
25000/50000
```

It should not include any number that has a double "/" in it.

I try to use the following query to extract the accurate result

My approach 1:

```
Select term from alpha where 
term like '%[0-9]/[0-9]%'
```

my approach 2

```
Select term from alpha where    (CASE 
        WHEN term Like '%/%' THEN Left(term, CHARINDEX('/', term)-1)
        Else term
        End
```

But I am not getting accurate result while doing approach 1. I am getting error in approach 2. Please help me to figure out the problem

Comment: If at all possible it would be ideal to stop storing delimited data like this. It is challenging to query because it violates 1NF.

Comment: @SeanLange: You can put a `.mdf` file in a `VARBINARY(max)` column too.

Comment: @Joshua I don't understand the context. Not sure what putting an mdf file in a varbinary(max) has to do with this question.

Comment: Explain your logic. You have 5 instances of "100/300" yet your expected results has 3 instances.

Comment: OP - you should put closure to your question by marking an answer as accepted. Gen Wan seems to have an elegant query.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select term from alpha 
where term like '%/%' -- >= one '/'
and term not like '%/%/%' -- < two '/'
```

Comment: I like this SQL. Nice and concise.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other approaches, this approach just gets term that has at least 1 `/` and then further restricts results to one that does not have 2 `/`.

See example here: https://rextester.com/LQI52271

```
create table alpha (
    term varchar(100)
);

insert into alpha values
('300/500/100')
,('25/50/15')
,('300/500')
,('100/300')
,('25/50/15')
,('100/300')
,('25000/50000')
,('100/300')
,('100/300')
,('25/50/15')
,('100/300/100')
,('300/500/100')
,('300/500/300')
,('25/50/15')
,('25000/50000')
,('100/300');

select term
from alpha
where term like '%/%'
    and len(REPLACE(term, '/', '')) = len(term) - 1
order by term;
```

**OUTPUT**

Note that the output is different from yours. In your input, there are indeed 5 instances of 100/300.

```
    term
1   100/300
2   100/300
3   100/300
4   100/300
5   100/300
6   25000/50000
7   25000/50000
8   300/500
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to count the number of `/` char and select only the rows with count equal to `1`:

Input

```
CREATE TABLE #alpha (
   term varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #alpha
   (term)
VALUES
   ('300/500/100'),
   ('25/50/15'),
   ('300/500'),
   ('100/300'),
   ('25/50/15'),
   ('100/300'),
   ('25000/50000'),
   ('100/300'),
   ('100/300'),
   ('25/50/15'),
   ('100/300/100'),
   ('300/500/100'),
   ('300/500/300'),
   ('25/50/15'),
   ('25000/50000'),
   ('100/300')
```

Statement

```
SELECT term 
FROM #alpha
WHERE 
   (term LIKE '%/%') AND
   (LEN(term) - LEN(REPLACE(term, '/', ''))) = 1
```

Output

```
--------------
term
--------------
300/500
100/300
100/300
25000/50000
100/300
100/300
25000/50000
100/300
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (just for fun) is to use the `hierarchyid` data type

**Example**

```
 Select *
  From  alpha
  Where try_convert(hierarchyid,'/'+term+'/').GetLevel() = 2
```

Comment: Nice use of rocket science, though it's just a "cross the street" problem.